# pushNamed throws an error by navigating to log in page with context

Tags: flutter

After signing up I show an approve alert. Clicking on the should bring the user to the log in page. I have to pass the location service to the login_screen otherwise the login was not starting after the first log in. But I get the following error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture 

===============================================================
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/loginScreen", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate 
this route.
Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1438:9)
#1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:1453:6)
#2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4173:37)
#3      NavigatorState.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4217:21)
#4      Navigator.pushNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1710:34)
#5      _RegisterScreenState._showMyDialog.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:sdx_patient_portal/presentation/auth/register_screen.dart:51:31)
#6      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1154:21)
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:654:11)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:311:5)
#10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:244:7)
#11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:630:9)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:625:13)
#15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#16     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:465:19)
#18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:445:22)
```

...
#25     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:382:7)
#26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#61a5f
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: possible
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(292.3, 416.0)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(52.6, 16.3)
button: 1
sent tap down
=======================
The loginScreen rout is registered in MyAPP:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  static LocationService? locationService = LocationService();

  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
    required this.homepage,
    required this.isLoggedIn,
    required this.isLightTheme,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool? isLoggedIn;
  final String homepage;
  final bool isLightTheme;

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LocationService? locationService;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MyApp.locationService = LocationService();
    PedometerService.instance.init();
    initializeLocation();
  }
  Future<void> initializeLocation() async {
    await MyApp.locationService?.getLocationOnchange(context);
    startLocationStream();
  }
  Future<void> startLocation() async {
    if (locationService != null) {
      await locationService!.getLocationOnchange(context);
      locationService!.getListener();
      startLocationStream();
    }
  }
  void resetLocationService() {
    locationService?.dispose();
    locationService = LocationService();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isLoggedIn ?? false) {
      if (locationService == null) {
        resetLocationService();
        startLocation();
      }
    } else {
      resetLocationService();
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Semdatex Patient Portal',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: widget.isLightTheme ? lightMode : darkMode,
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      initialRoute: widget.homepage,
      home: PushMessaging(
        isLoggedIn: widget.isLoggedIn,
        homepage: widget.homepage,
        title: "Semdatex Patient Portal",
      ),
      routes: {
        '/questionnairePushNotificationRoot': (context) => const QuestionnaireRoot(),
        '/singleChoiceNew': (context) => const SelectionWindow(),
        '/exercisePrescriptionPage': (context) => const PrescriptionHome(),
        '/prescription': (context) => const PrescriptionHome(),
        '/multipleChoice': (context) => const MultipleChoice(),
        '/scale': (context) => const Scale(),
        '/textfield': (context) => const FreeTextfield(),
        '/endScreen': (context) => const EndScreen(),
        '/loginScreen': (context) => LoginScreen(locationService: locationService!),
        '/registerScreen': (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
        '/error_report': (context) => const PrescriptionHome(),
        '/actsessns': (context) => const ActivitiesLineChart(title: 'ActivitySessions'),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And the register_screen is:

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 const RegisterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  User user = User("", "", "");
  String url = urlBase + "v1/mob/register";

  Future save() async {
    var res = await post(url, {'email': user.email, 'password': user.password})
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (res.statusCode == 400) {
      _showMyDialog(res.body, 400);
    } else if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      _showMyDialog(res.body, 200);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showMyDialog(text, statusCode) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('alert'.tr()),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(text),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  'approve'.tr(),
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (statusCode == 200) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loginScreen');
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'loginScreen'.tr(),
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Timely',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 30),
                      )),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.email),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        user.email = val;
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'emailEmpty'.tr();
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'email'.tr(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        user.password = val;
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'passwordEmpty'.tr();
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.password),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'password'.tr(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forgotPassword');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'forgotPassword'.tr(),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      height: 50,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                        child: Text(
                          'signUp'.tr(),
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            save();
                          }
                        },
                      )),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('haveAnAccount'.tr()),
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'login'.tr(),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loginScreen');
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

This one did not help either:

```
 onPressed: () {
  if (statusCode == 200) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/loginScreen');
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
},...
```

log in screen is like:

```
 class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.locationService,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final LocationService locationService;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  User user = User("", "", "");

  String url = urlBase + "v1/mob/login";
  String urlLanguage = urlBase + "v1/mob/language";

  Future save() async {
    String? token = await SharedPref.getFCMToken();
    var res = await post(url, {
      'email': user.email.toLowerCase().trim(),
      'password': user.password,
      'firebaseToken': token,
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    if (res.body.isEmpty) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('loginUnsuccessfull'.tr());
      }
      _showMyDialog();
    } else {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      if (data["patientNumber"] == null) {
        _showMyDialog();
      } else {
        await savePatientNumber(data["patientNumber"], data["lastAccess"]);
        await SharedPref.saveLoginSharedPreference(true);
        try {
          sendMetadata();
          widget.locationService.initListener();
          startLocationStream();
        } catch (e) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(e);
          }
        }
        try{ rest...
```

How should I navigate back to the login screen?

Comment: I removed the context from the loginScreen,  corected the MyApp and changed the other parts, but i still get Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/loginScreen", null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different `BuildContext`s in your case:

1. The origin context where you define your routes. Using this one allows you to navigate without issue.
2. The dialog context, which knows nothing about your routes. This is the source of the error.

Since all context variables have the same name inside the `_showMyDialog` method, the issue is caused by scoping (the nearest variable with the name will be accessed). Please read the comments below to understand:

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context, text, statusCode) async {
  ///                                   ^^^^^^^ origin context
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      ///                  ^^^^^^^ this context is the one in scope, but this
      ///                          is the dialog context, not the origin
      ///                          context from above.
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Alert"),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(text),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("Continue", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            onPressed: () {
              if (statusCode == 200) {
                /// At this point 'context' refers to the dialog context.
                ///
                /// Your navigator is then being asked to push a page using
                /// the dialog context, which knows nothing about your routes.
                ///
                /// Output: Unable to find generator error.
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage');
              } else {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

There are some solutions:

1. Differentiate the two contexts by naming them differently.
2. Use the return value of your dialog to respond to in the origin context.
3. Use a navigator key (I leave this one as an exercise to you).

Let's see what option 1 looks like (read comments for explanation):

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog(BuildContext context, text, statusCode) async {
  ///                                   ^^^^^^^ Origin context.
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
      ///                  ^^^^^^^^ We name this context 'dialogContext', in
      ///                           order to avoid confusion with the context
      ///                           passed to this method.
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Alert"),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(text),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text("Continue", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            onPressed: () {
              if (statusCode == 200) {
                /// Pop the dialog using its context.
                Navigator.pop(dialogContext);

                /// Push the new route using the origin context.
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/secondPage');
              } else {
                Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

That works because now we are navigating (`pushNamed`) using the context that actually knows how to generate the route, and we pop the dialog using its own context.

For option 2, I'll give you general description:

1. Note that `showDialog` returns a `Future<T?>`, therefore, we can `await showDialog` to retrieve an optional value returned by the dialog.
2. The signature of the pop method is: `void pop<T extends Object?>([T? result])`, so let's return a result when the user taps on the dialog's confirm button (the action).

This means that you could define your dialog's actions as such:

```
actions: <Widget>[
  TextButton(
    child: const Text('approve', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
    /// Whenever the button is pressed, we will pop the dialog and
    /// return whether the statusCode was 200 or not.
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, statusCode == 200),
  ),
],
```

And in the code that calls `_showMyDialog`, you use the value of the future to determine how to proceed:

```
onPressed: () {
  /// When the dialog is popped, it will have the result of 'statusCode == 200'.
  _showMyDialog(context, "Hello World", 200).then(
    (didApprove) {
      /// The future returns T?, so check if it's null, and then check
      /// if it's true.
      if (didApprove != null && didApprove) {
        /// Navigate to your login screen, this works because the context 
        /// in this case is the origin context.
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loginScreen');
      }
    },
  );
},
```